# Application ends without throwing exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, exception

The following code

```
new System.Threading.Timer(state =>
{
     var query = "Select Caption from Win32_OperatingSystem";
     var objectQuery = new WqlObjectQuery(query);
     var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objectQuery);
     searcher.Get();
     //unreachable code
}, null, 0, 1000);
```

ends my App immediately without throwing exceptions.
If you copy and paste these lines in a new Console project you probably won't be able to reproduce the problem.
The code above is a small portion of my Windows Service and it is likely the cause of the problem. The above code is exercised by unit tests which run normally without throwing exceptions.
The last executed line before the problem occurs is not always the same. 
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced

```
this.timer = new Timer(
    TimerCallback,
    null,
    Settings.Default.CheckDelay,
    Settings.Default.CheckInterval);
```

by

```
new Thread(delegate()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(Settings.Default.CheckDelay);
        while (isRunning)
        {
            TimerCallback(null);
            Thread.Sleep(Settings.Default.CheckInterval);
        }
    }).Start();
```

Which is uglier, but solves my undebuggable problem